# Adding vertical lines around row vectors in block matrices

Tags: matrices, arrays, nicematrix

I would like to produce a 3x3 block matrix with a layout shown in the left figure below. The matrix is split by a row vector `d-e-f` and a column vector `b-e-h` (so `e` represents a 1x1 submatrix). I would like to add two horizontal and two vertical lines to separate the 9 blocks (4 matrices, 4 vectors, 1 scalar).

I am using the `NiceArray` commands of the [`nicematrix` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix), which work as intended if I use two-row blocks (see the left matrix below). However, when I am trying to typeset the row vector `d-e-f` using one-row blocks (i.e. changing `\Block{2-2}{d}` to `\Block{1-2}{d}` and so on), the vertical lines break (see the example on the right). Adding/removing the `\hline` commands has no effect on the vertical lines. I am using TeX Live 2019 with `nicematrix` version 3.7.

Is there a way I can keep vertical lines around submatrix `e` without using two-row blocks?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pNiceArray}{cc|c|cc}[margin]
    \Block{2-2}{a} & & \Block{2-1}{b} & \Block{2-2}{c} & \\
                   & &                &                & \\\hline
    \Block{2-2}{d} & & \Block{2-1}{e} & \Block{2-2}{f} & \\
                   & &                &                & \\\hline
    \Block{2-2}{g} & & \Block{2-1}{h} & \Block{2-2}{i} & \\
                   & &                &                & \\
\end{pNiceArray}
\quad
\begin{pNiceArray}{cc|c|cc}[margin]
    \Block{2-2}{a} & & \Block{2-1}{b} & \Block{2-2}{c} & \\
                   & &                &                & \\
    \Block{1-2}{d} & & \Block{1-1}{e} & \Block{1-2}{f} & \\\hline
    \Block{2-2}{g} & & \Block{2-1}{h} & \Block{2-2}{i} & \\
                   & &                &                & \\
\end{pNiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

Update: ultimately, I'd like to substitute the `a`...`i` with formulas representing the submatrices, e.g. `A_{00}`, `a_{01}^\mathsf{T}`, etc.
I'd also like to illustrate that `a` and `i` are square matrices but `c` and `g` are not necessarily square ones.

Here is an example output with realistic values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1mm}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{8pt}
\[
\begin{pNiceArray}{ccc|c|ccccc}[margin]
    \Block{3-3}{A_{00}} & & & \Block{3-1}{a_{01}} & \Block{3-4}{A_{20}^\mathsf{T}} & & & \\
     & & & & & & & \\
     & & & & & & & \\ \hline
     % I'd like to use the following line but it doesn't work as expected:
     %\Block{1-3}{a_{01}^\mathsf{T}} & & & \Block{1-1}{0} & \Block{1-4}{a_{21}^\mathsf{T}} & & & \\
     % two-row blocks are fine:
     \Block{2-3}{a_{01}^\mathsf{T}} & & & \Block{2-1}{0} & \Block{2-4}{a_{21}^\mathsf{T}} & & & \\
     & & & & & & & \\ \hline
     \Block{4-3}{A_{20}} & & & \Block{4-1}{a_{21}} & \Block{4-4}{A_{22}} & & & \\
     & & & & & & & \\
     & & & & & & & \\
     & & & & & & & \\
\end{pNiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about: `\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\left(
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
    {a} & {b} & {c}  \\ \hline
    {d} & {e} & {f}  \\ \hline
    {g} & {h} & {i}  \\
\end{array}
\right)
\]

\end{document}`  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0N71i.png

Comment: I've updated the question with a more complex example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar as suggested @leandriis in his comment. Your blocks are simulated with more space around submatrix:

**Edit:**

Considering  matrix content as you provided in edited question

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,
            makecell}    % new

\begin{document}
\[\setcellgapes{3pt}
  \makegapedcells
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|c|ccc}
    &           &&          &&              &   \\
    & A_{00}    && a_{01}   &&   A_{20}^T   &   \\
    &           &&          &&              &   \\   \hline
    & a_{01}^T  && 0        &&  f           &   \\   \hline
    &           &&          &&              &   \\
    & A_{20}    && a_{21}   &&  A_{22}^T    &   \\
    &           &&          &&              &   \\
\end{array}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

Note: empty rows and column are add for emphasizing where dimension submatrix are bigger than `1 x 1`. If this is not necessary, simple dropout them out.

[image]

Comment: I'd like to use more lengthy formulas such as `A_{00}` and `a_{01}^T`. Centering these (horizontally and vertically) needs quite a lot of fiddling which I'd like to delegate to the nicematrix package. I've updated the question with this information.

Comment: centering of cells' contents in `nicematrix` is the same as in the ordinary array. Please, edit your question and show more realistic matrix, that we can see your specific, which you believe, that is not possible center in`array`.

Comment: I've clarified the question with an additional example.

Comment: Seems good - upvoted. I think the main limitation of this approach is that handling even-sized dimensions such as a 2x2 submatrix is verbose due to the need to use `multicolumn` and `multirow` at the same time. The latter also exits math mode so the top-left cell would become something like `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{$A_{00}$}}`.

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas, sorry, I'm lost in your new demands. From given information I can only say, that for drawing this simple vertical and horizontal lines you not need `nicematrix`. In case, that you like to interrupt this line, than `nicematrix` has advantage. I'm convinced, that both answer solve problem exposed in question. If you now have new questions, please ask new question.

Comment: Fair enough, this indeed answers my original question and `makecell`'s `\makegapedcells` that does the job well. Thanks! One remark: your usepackage commands seem broken, can you edit them?

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas, you are right. Comma was lost at editing answer ... corrected now.

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you. i will correct asap ...

Answer (score 3):

It turns out this is a bug in the current version of the `nicematrix` package. This has been fixed in version 3.8 (2020-01-02) and is available on CTAN.

If you're stuck with an older version for some reason, the bug can be worked around by adding `\vline` at the end of the affected cells. Applying this on the minimal working example gives the desired output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1mm}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{8pt}
\[
\begin{pNiceArray}{ccc|c|ccccc}[margin]
    \Block{3-3}{A_{00}} & & & \Block{3-1}{a_{01}} & \Block{3-4}{A_{20}^\mathsf{T}} & & & \\
    & & & & & & & \\
    & & & & & & & \\ \hline
    \Block{1-3}{a_{01}^\mathsf{T}} & & \vline & \Block{1-1}{0} \vline & \Block{1-4}{a_{21}^\mathsf{T}} & & & \\\hline
    \Block{4-3}{A_{20}} & & & \Block{4-1}{a_{21}} & \Block{4-4}{A_{22}} & & & \\
    & & & & & & & \\
    & & & & & & & \\
    & & & & & & & \\
\end{pNiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good work. You could put, if you prefer, `$\top$` or `$\intercal$` commands instead of `\mathsf`.

Answer (score 2):

A variant solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} %

\begin{document}


\[ \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
  \left[\,\:\begin{matrix}
     a & \vrule & b & \vrule & c \\
    \hline
     d & \vrule & e & \vrule & f \\
    \hline
     g & \vrule & h &\vrule & i
    \end{matrix}
\,\: \right]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]